# Alarm as full charged battery notification

Tags: notifications, xiaomi

**Xiaomi MIUI10Global8.12.20/Redmi Note4**

While trying to find a way to set an alarm as a full charge notification,[this search result popped up](https://c.mi.com/thread-2511709-1-0.html/id="postmessage_12292838")***(manually set the alarm)***.

Since this a frequently required feature, is there an app or something to automatically achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed an app called [Battery Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=simple.batttery.alarm) (free, no ads).

The app notifies the user when the battery level reaches a certain threshold.

[image: screenshot of the app]

By setting the "Max Alarm" to 100%, the app will notify the user if the battery is fully charged.

Comment: A recommendation by the author himself... Anyway a nice and clean app, even without INTERNET permission :)

Answer (score 0):

Bing gives the worst search results!

After a google search  [the following results popped up](https://www.maketecheasier.com/notify-when-android-battery-full/)

[Full Battery & Theft Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pextor.batterychargeralarm&hl=en_IN) is a popular app to achieve the result.